# How to extend custom view in ember tools

Tags: ember.js

I am tryin to use ember js with jquery mobile ttps://github.com/LuisSala/emberjs-jqm

how can i extend custom view in ember tools. I tried something like this and it didnt work.

```
var MobileBaseView = Ember.View.extend({
    attributeBindings:['data-role']
});
module.exports = MobileBaseView;
```

and

```
var MobileBaseView = require('MobileBaseView');
var PageView = MobileBaseView.extend({
    'data-role': 'page'
});
module.exports = PageView;
```

it did not work

*UPDATED*********
after implementing suggestion by kingpin(thanks). I observed that multi level extend is not working in my case.

I have

**mobile base view :**

```
var MobileBaseView = Ember.View.extend({
    attributeBindings:['data-role']
});
module.exports = MobileBaseView;
```

**toolbarsbase view :**

```
var ToolbarBaseView = App.MobileBaseView.extend({

    attributeBindings:['data-position'],
    'data-position': function() {
        if (this.get('isFullScreen')) {
            return 'fullscreen'
        }

        if (this.get('isFixed')) {
            return 'fixed'
        }
        return ''
    }.property('isFixed', 'isFullScreen').cacheable(),
    isFixed: true,
    isFullsScreen: false
});
module.exports = ToolbarBaseView;
```

and a line in my template

```
{{view App.ToolbarBaseView}}
```

this work fine

but as soon as i add one more view
**header view**

```
var HeaderView = App.ToolbarBaseView.extend({
    'data-role': 'header'
});
module.exports = HeaderView;
```

and add line

```
{{view App.HeaderView}}
```

i get error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined

## SOLVED

got this working with ember app kit

```
import ToolbarBaseView from 'appkit/views/toolbar_base_view';

var HeaderView = ToolbarBaseView.extend({
    'data-role': 'header'
});

export default HeaderView;
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving your problem is breaking it down into separate issues.  If you are having trouble with views, here's an example of views working

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OhUFOXe/2/edit

```
App.CustomView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'p',
  templateName: 'customView',
  myColor: 'N/A',
  attributeBindings:['data-color'],
  'data-color': 'purple', 
  didInsertElement: function(){
    var col = this.$().data('color');
    this.set('myColor',col);
  }
});

App.OtherCustomView = App.CustomView.extend({
  'data-color': 'green',
  templateName: 'otherCustomView'
});
```

If it isn't the view that isn't working correctly then possibly it's your module framework.  Is the view working, just a portion of it isn't being injected properly?

If the framework appears to be correct, and the view is being injected (possibly wrong) is the problem with jquery mobile?  Is it expecting the element to be something other than a div?

Comment: What other problem do you have?

Comment: So it looks to me like the problem is your module framework (is it requirejs?) isn't associating your views with your ember application.  So really when you try and do {{view App.Something}} Something doesn't exist under the App framework.  Technically it'd be {{view Something}} which also probably wouldn't work.

Comment: it is commonjs. https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-tools I guess there is some update expected on it https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-tools/issues/80 I was hoping to try some work around. i will some more things.... thank you.